# What are my largest org mode sections?

Tags: org-mode

My .org file is almost 2MB large. How can I narrow down what headers/sub-headers take so much space?

Comment: In case it's due to many *lines* of content, then a really trivial approach is to enable `display-line-numbers-mode` with only the headings visible, and look for a really big jump.  Then expand/repeat as necessary to drill down.  To check actual character counts, you may need to write some code -- more or less just checking how much `(point)` changed between each heading, and maybe showing that as a proportion of `(point-max)`.

Comment: @jagrg Post as answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See
[org-treeusage.el](https://github.com/mtekman/org-treeusage.el).
It was added recently to the MELPA archive.

> This library provides a minor mode for peeking at the line or
>   character usage of each heading in an org-mode file with respect to
>   the parent heading, allowing users with large org files to see the
>   distribution of heading content and make informed decisions on where
>   to prune, refile, or archive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python script [org-du](https://github.com/novoid/org-du/) to produce line counts per section, using the same format as the `du` command line tool.  This can then be piped to `xdu` for a graphical display.